# High goal setting and bipolar disorder (BD): How someone diagnosed with BD can mitigate the risk of setting unrealistic goals?

Tags: bipolar-disorder, goals

I read the article *Identify in bipolar disorder: self-worth and achievement*; This paper opened my eyes about how people diagnosed with BD can set unrealistic or very hard to achieve goals. If the biology basis for this kind of behaviour is related to dopamine in the brain; can Dialectical Behaviour Therapy (to treat Borderline Personality Disorder) or The Life Goals Program or any other psychotherapy help?